# Android Room TypeConverter for Double

Tags: android, android-room

I am trying to use custom TypeConverter for Android Room Persistance Library as shown in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/TypeConverter.html). Main idea is to format all Sqlite SUM selects that Android Room Dao is preforming.

My code:

```
 @TypeConverter
public static double toDouble(String str) {
    return FormatHelper.formatAmount(Double.parseDouble(str));
}

@TypeConverter
public static String fromDouble(double doub) {
    return String.valueOf(FormatHelper.formatAmount(doub));
}
```

I already tried to clear data and rebuild the app. 
Converters for Date in the same class are working.
Does the Android TypeConverters not supports Primitive variables?

**EDIT:**

I register TypeConverter in RoomDatabase class so it is used across whole database.

More specifically about my problem: if I have Query in my Dao class like this:

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM production_plan_item")
Double getActivePlanItemsCount();
```

It may sometimes return value like 2.30000000000001.

I thought that Type converters are used to process returned value of queries. And every time before I save double to database or select double from it, my TypeConverter would round the double for me and I would not have to round it every time I select something.

Otherwise I have to round every single selected double manually.

Comment: "Main idea is to format all Sqlite SUM selects that Android Room Dao is preforming" -- that makes no sense to me. Formatting is not the responsibility of a persistence library. That is the responsibility of a presenter or some other piece of code associated with the user interface. Beyond that, where are you registering these `TypeConverter` methods? What are you expecting them to affect?

Comment: @CommonsWare I edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought that Type converters are used to process returned value of queries

Your `@TypeConverter` methods convert between `double` and `String`. `SUM` will not return a `String`. Your `@Query` method is returning a `Double`. Hence, neither of these `@TypeConverter` methods will be relevant, since there is no `String`<->`double` conversion taking place.

> Otherwise I have to round every single selected double manually.

Perhaps you should be using fewer `REAL` columns in your database schema.